# store uint8_t in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, iphone, nsmutablearray, uint8t

in my program i am getting my receiving data from sensors in uint8_t type. I need to store those data in a NSMutable array.

i created a NSMutable array

```
NSmutableArray *test;
```

initialize it

```
test = [[test alloc]init];
```

Then i tried to store data in my array

```
[test addObject:Message.data7];
```

Message.data7 is in uint8_t format

But it want allow me to store like that way ,

Can any one explain me how to do that.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't store simple primitives in `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray`. However, you can convert it to a `NSNumber` and store that:

```
[test addObject:@(Message.data7)];
```

When you want to retrieve the value from the array:

```
uint8_t value = (uint8_t)[test[index] unsignedCharValue];
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and really appreciate it. But some one replied here , that we can use C array "uint8_t array[]" to store data without converting it. I like to use that method because if i convert the data it ll cost extra processing power. Because my sensors are receiving whole bunch of data per a minute. So if you have any idea about how to use C array  can u explain it with sample code . Thanks

Comment: If the number of sensor readings that you're going to store in the array is fixed, then a uint8_t array is the best approach, but if it's going to be variable or you need the array to grow dynamically, it's less work to use a NSMutableArray.

Comment: oh ok .. cool :).. yes i need my array grow dinamically. thanks for your kind reply

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C objects can store objects only.

`unit8_t` is not an obj-c object hence you can't add to `NSArray`.

You need to convert that value to some compatible type(any objective-c object) then you can store it.

```
uint8_t value = 10;
NSArray *array = @[@(value)]; //boxed to NSNumber, and added to array.
```

**In your case:**

```
[test addObject:@(Message.data7)];
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store simple type inside `NSMutableArray`. You may only store objects.

You have 2 way of doing it, store `NSNumber` and convert them back to uint8_t when reading from the array or used a C array `uint8_t array[]`

Comment: thanks for your reply and yes i want use 2 nd method you explained. Using C array. Because using that method i can store raw data instead of converting it. It ll cost extra processing to convert data. Because my sensors are receiving lots of data per a minute. So can you explain with some sample code if you can how to use uint8_t array[] and store data in there . THanks

Answer (score 1):

`uint8_t` is defined as `unsigned char` in `_uint_8_t.h` so you can use `NSNumber` `initWithUnsignedChar:` and store that in the array and then use the `unsignedCharValue` and cast that back to `uint8_t`.